# SQL Server 2008 Convert String to Datetime question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string column in a table that display data as `"CXL P/D 08/15/13"`

I'm trying to convert this column to datetime, but I can't figure out how to extract only date and change the data type.

`Cast(RIGHT(RTRIM(Trade_Date) ,8)as datetime)` I'm trying this statement but it doesn't work

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Use [CONVERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and specify 1 as the date time style `1 = mm/dd/yy`.

```
CONVERT(datetime, RIGHT('CXL P/D 08/15/13', 8), 1)
```